# Finding the block using row and column indices - Sudoku Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and am implementing a Sudoku solver. I have a method which returns the set of all possible values a particular element int the grid can take and it works. However, I think that there is a much better way to do this. The problem arises when I try to check the values of other elements in the same block. Is there any other way (than the one shown below) I can find a relationship between the row, column and block to result in cleaner code?

Note that r and c are the row and column indices, respectively, and are given as parameters to the function.

```
   val i=
    if(r==0|r==1|r==2){
      if(c==0||c==1||c==2)
        0
        else if(c==3|c==4|c==5)
          1
          else 
            2
    } else if (r==3|r==4|r==5){
       if(c==0||c==1||c==2)
        3
        else if(c==3||c==4||c==5)
          4
          else 
            5
    } else {
      if(c==0||c==1||c==2)
        6
        else if(c==3||c==4||c==5)
          7
          else
            8
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def i(r:Int,c:Int) = r/3*3 + c/3
```

Although you'll probably want to find a better name/ add comments, it's not really the most intuitive function...

Comment: Great, understood!! Managed to fix. Thanks :-)